# Differentiating Magnolia TemplatingFunction.isPreviewMode()

Tags: magnolia

Currently in Magnolia CMS, there's a public method to decide whether user were in preview mode called `info.magnolia.templating.functions.TemplatingFunctions.isPreviewMode()`

I have added this function and tested previewing a page in AdminCentral - Page Editor, it is working fine and returns `true`. However, when I open a normal public page, it is also returns `true`.

My expected behaviour is :

1. Previewing page in AdminCentral, returns `true`
2. Opening page in public site, returns `false`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Looking at the source code, it should work like this _only_ if you have a parameter `mgnlPreview` set to `true` on the request.

Answer (score 0):

What is the full URL are you visiting? There is a difference between isEditMode and isPreviewMode ...